# How can I read excel file by using objective-c iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, excel, ios7

I need to pull out the excel file to interface that user can only read the information in file.

what is the solution to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

The most easy way to solve this is first, convert the Excel file to CSV format, which stands for Comma Seperated Value. Meaning it's formatted like: cell 1,cell 2,cell 3. And a new line for each row.

The second is to read the file into a String which can be done in two ways, depending if you have it local or not. Let's say you have it on a server.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://urltoyour.excel/file.csv"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentOfURL:url];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithData:data];
```

Then you can easily convert this to arrays using

```
NSArray *lines = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Now you have each excel line in that array. Now for each line you probably want the columns in an array too, you can do that using:

```
NSMutableArray *finalArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString *line in lines) {
     NSArray *array = [line componentsSeperatedByString:@","];
     [finalArray addObject:array];
}
```

Good luck and let me know if that works out for you!